# Change Cell Background Every 5 Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, colors

Hello I want to change the color of my UITableView Cells ever 5 cells, so I would have green for cell one blue for cell two and so on. Then once I hit 5 cells, I want the colors to start over.

This is what I have so far:

```
if(indexPath.row % 5 == 0){
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else  if (indexPath.row % 4 == 0) {
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else  if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
} else  if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
} else if(indexPath.row % 1 == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: What results are you getting thus far? Your code looks similar to what I'd implement for your idea. Have you tried putting this code into `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cel forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`? Also, just a thought, but I'd put the logic in reverse order, since row '4' (brown) will always go through the '2' branch (black). Or, you could do `int row = indexPath.row % 5;` and then do your `if/else/then` block based on that value.

Comment: What I have now the colors repeat every other cell. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that every other cell is black, right? Which makes total sense based on logical processing order of your logic! ;-) I would expect: 1) black, 2) undefined (probably white as default background), 3) black, 4) white, 5) black, 6) blue, etc...

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant I'm currently fixing the logic ;-) it already looks better.

Comment: Ok this is what I have now, it's still printing out of order. I updated it in the question.

Comment: The reason you are getting dupes is because 12 % 4 and 12 % 3 both == 0. See my answer below for a better approach, that solves the modulo problem as well as increasing performance and code maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if(indexPath.row % 5 == 0)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
else  if (indexPath.row % 5 == 1)
{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else  if (indexPath.row % 5 == 2)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
else  if (indexPath.row % 5 == 3)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else if(indexPath.row % 5 == 4)
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

You want to keep the modulus divisor the same -- its the remainder that is actually going to be changing

Comment: Check my answer, I believe it is a bit better because there's not so much if/else getting out of control, and it also uses `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` instead of `cell.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 3):

You need to modulo against the same number, not different numbers. This should point you in the right direction:

```
static NSArray* rowColors;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    rowColors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor yellowColor]];
});

int rowMod = indexPath.row % rowColors.count;

UIColor* color = rowColors[rowMod];

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
```

This approach does a few things better than your current approach:

- It performs % against the same number, which is the core logic problem in what you posted
- It dynamically uses rowColors.count, in case you want to add extra colors (e.g., change every 7 rows instead of every 5)
- It uses an array so you don't have if/else-if/else-if/else-if getting out of control
- It sets backgroundColor on cell.contentView instead of cell, which is the proper way to set a background color
- The array is static and only written to once, to ensure good performance and not result in a ton of memory allocation each time you setup a cell

Hope it helps!

Comment: Excellent answer. (Voted)